# fourfold display in matplotlib using polar axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to create a [fourfold display](http://datavis.ca/papers/4fold/4fold.pdf) in matplotlib:

[image]

but can't get the logic of the polar axis. This is what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# radius of each bar 
radii = [10,  15, 20, 25] 

# Value - width 
width = np.pi/ 2 

# angle of each bar 
theta = [0,90,180,270]

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width)
plt.show()
```

not sure what I am missing but I just want four "equal" areas which touch each others. What I can't get to work is

- How to "control"  the angles ? I mean to have all four "slides" being in `[0,90], [90,180], [180, 270], [270, 360]`.
- I do not understand what "width" corresponds to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`theta` is expected to be in radians, not degrees.

If you just slightly tweak your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# radius of each bar
radii = [10,  15, 20, 25]

# Value - width
width = np.pi/ 2

# angle of each bar
theta = np.radians([0,90,180,270])

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

You'll get what you'd expect:

[image]

On a side note, for the exact plot you're making it might make more sense to use 4 `Wedge`s on a rectangular plot with centered spines.

Comment: Great ! thanks. not sure I understand what you mean with "4 Wedge".

Answer (score 2):

**In case somebody else is interested here is what I came up**

To use the example of Berkeley admission in the paper one first need to standardized the values (to equate margins) using [iterative proportional fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_proportional_fitting)

```
def ContTableIPFP(x1ContTable):
''' poor man IPFP
    compute iterative proportional fitting for 
    a 2 X 2 contingency table
    Input : 
      a 2x2 contingency table as numpy array
    Output : 
       numpy array with values standarized to equate margins
 '''
 import numpy as np 
 #Margins 
 xSumRows = np.sum(x1ContTable, axis = 0).tolist()
 xSumCols = np.sum(x1ContTable, axis = 1).tolist()

 # Seed 
 xq0 = x1ContTable/x1ContTable
 # Iteration 1 : we adjust by row sums (i.e. using the sums of the columns)
 xq1 = np.array([
            (xq0[0] * xSumCols[0]).astype(float) / np.sum(xq0, axis = 0).tolist()[0],
            (xq0[1] * xSumCols[1]).astype(float) / np.sum(xq0, axis = 0).tolist()[1],
           ]
           )
 #Iteration 2 : adjust by columns (i.e. using sums of rows) 
 xq2 = np.array([
            (xq1[:,0] * xSumRows[0]).astype(float) / np.sum(xq1, axis = 0).tolist()[0],
            (xq1[:,1] * xSumRows[1]).astype(float) / np.sum(xq1, axis = 0).tolist()[1],
           ]
           )

 return xq2.T
```

and then plot

```
def FourfoldDisplay(radii):
  ''' radii = [10,  15, 20, 25]
   '''
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   # Value - width
   width = np.pi/ 2
   # angle of each bar
   theta = np.radians([0,90,180,270])
   ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)    
   bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, alpha=0.5)

   #labels 
   ax.set_xticklabels([])
   ax.set_yticks([])
   #plt.axis('off')

   plt.show()
```

**to use**

```
import numpy as np 
x1 = np.array([
            [1198, 1493], 
            [557, 1278]
            ])

x2 = ContTableIPFP(x1).flatten() 
FourfoldDisplay(x2)
```